# started service recreates after the process is terminated

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying a simple android app that starts and stops a simple service with `startService()`. I notice that each time I manually terminate the app process (by closing the app), another instance of my service is created.

In other words, the service that I created isn't destroyed, and an additional service is created. I can see that the `onDestroy()` isn't called, and the `onCreate()` & `onStart()` get called again

Why is that? How can I prevent it? You can see the source code I'm using in this example: [Source Code](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/service/android-service-example/)

Comment: Closing an app should not normally terminate its process (though that can happen under extreme memory pressure).  Nor is it normal for a component like an Activity or Service to be destroyed when it is in a compatible configuration and can simply be started again.

Comment: When writing closing the app I meant double clicking the home button and swiping the app. Are you saying this doesn't terminate the process?

Comment: Swiping out of the recents list will terminate it, but that's not the normal way a user is encouraged to leave an app (normally, you just "walk away" to something else, and leave the cleaning up decision to Android's resource management).  When a process is terminated abruptly, onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: Ok, but then why do onCreate() & onStart() get called again right away?
Are there 2 instances of the service running now?

Comment: Presumably because you have started your service in a such a way that Android believes it still has important work to do, hence after the original process containing that (and the app) is killed by swiping out of recents, a new process containing just the service *may be* created *by some versions* of Android.

Comment: Sounds a bit weird.. BTW the same happens on my 4.2.2 android galaxy 3 and on the emulator running the latest android on nexus 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your `Service` using `Context.startService()` and your `Service` returns `START_STICKY` from its `onStartCommand()` then the system is expecting the `Service` to either be explicitly stopped via something calling `Context.stopService()` or the `Service` itself calling `stopSelf()`.  When you use the Recents screen to "swipe away" your app, you are forcefully killing the process but not explicitly stopping the `Service`.

Comment: So how would you suggest to handle this scenario?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and how is your `Service` used/needed?  If all you are using the `Service` to do is handle some background task while your app is active, consider using an `IntentService` which will spawn a background thread for you to handle the `Intent` you pass then automatically die when it is done servicing all requests.

Comment: My goal is creating a service that will run in the background all the time, you could take whatsapp for an example. I guess I can deal with the OS destroying and recreating it from time to time, but in the case I described the standard callbacks aren't being called...

Comment: As already explained, onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called in the case of process death.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is correct: the lifecycle callbacks will not be called in the case of process termination (whether via the user as you describe or via OOM condition.)  Since your `Service` is automatically being restarted, the system retains that it was running and the process was killed for some reason.  So as resources are available to bring it back to life it will, which is what you are seeing.